# How i can solve this issue of USB data transfer?

Tags: usb, windows, usb-connection-mode

I am using oppo A1k cell phone,Its Android version is 9. But when i try to connect it with my Laptop running windows 10, and out of 3 options(charge only,transfer files,transfer photos) i select transfer file option because i want to transfer files from my mobile to Laptop but i still couldn't see my phone appearing in my PC. It does appear but only for a very small instant, and then the window shown in attached snapshot keeps opening again and again
[image]

Comment: Windows users usually need to [install OEM USB drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb). You may need to find one for OPPO devices from other sources though.

Comment: @AndrewT. drivers are required even for MTP? Just for my knowledge. I don't remember doing that ever. Though I'm not a fan of either; Windows or MTP.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I can't be sure myself, though I've had an experience with some devices even just to get it recognized on Windows PC. But perhaps that's for ADB since I never use MTP either...

Comment: @AndrewT. I'm not sure either but I think MTP is a hardware agnostic class like USB Mass Storage class i.e. one doesn't have to install a driver to use a thumb drive.